# Spring Boot Query or Hibernate problem with validation Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing a little project for my university, but I got a problem. I'm thinking about it for 5 days and still don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]
    at com.project.warehouse.service.impl.CartServiceImpl.addCartbyUserIdAndItemId(CartServiceImpl.java:54)
    at com.project.warehouse.controller.AddToCartController.addCartWithItem(AddToCartController.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90)
```

```
@Query("Select addCart FROM AddToCart addCart WHERE addCart.user_id=:user_id and addCart.item.id=:item_id")
    Optional<AddToCart> getCartByProductIdAnduserId(@Param("item_id")Long item_id, @Param("user_id")Long user_id);
```

```
@Override
    public List<AddToCart> addCartbyUserIdAndItemId(long itemId, long userId, int quantity, double price) throws Exception {
        
            try {
                if(addToCartRepository.getCartByProductIdAnduserId(userId, itemId).isPresent()) {
                    throw new Exception("Product is already exist.");
                }
                
                AddToCart obj = new AddToCart();
                obj.setQuantity(quantity);
                obj.setUser_id(userId);
                Item item = itemService.getItemById(itemId);
                
                obj.setItem(item); 
                //TODO price has to check with qty
                obj.setPrice(price);
                addToCartRepository.save(obj);      
                return this.getCartByUserId(userId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.error("" + e .getMessage());
                throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
            }
    }
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private String description;
    
    private int quantity;
    
    private double price;
    
    private boolean inStock;

    public Integer getItemId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setItemId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public boolean isInStock() {
        return inStock;
    }

    public void setInStock(boolean inStock) {
        this.inStock = inStock;
    }
```

I checked every post with similar subject. Query looks good, I was sending request by frontend (react) and i'm getting the same by Postman. Maybe you will know what is happening here. Hibernate version is  5.6.8 final

Comment: the parameter "item_id" is Long, but the variable "id" of Item is Integer. Maybe this one can be the problem.

Comment: Oh Man! You are right! Sorry so much, probably I was tired or blind, Now is working. Thank you so much